# breaking up strings with explode and foreach

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many

I'm Trying to get a php string to break down into individual words, search for them in a database and then add the results into another database..

I currently have the string like this

"SDGCC, ARISE, SDGFS"

I want to search in the login tags table for tags LIKE these words i'm using this

> SELECT * FROM `logintags` WHERE `tag` LIKE '%string%'

so that each tag is taken from the string i've tried using explode and foreach but it doesn't seem to be getting the desired effect.

> $string = $_POST['tags'];
>
> $tags = explode(',' $string);
>
> foreach($tags as $key) {
>
> > $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `dept_logintags` WHERE `tag` LIKE '%".$key."%'");
> >     $r = mysql _fetch _object($query);
> >
> > $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `briefings_logintags` (`id`, `briefing_id`, `logintag_id`) VALUES (NULL, '$id', '".$r->id."')");
>
> }

the effect i'm trying to create is for each tag create a reference between the tag id and the briefing id...

However it seems only to be putting one correct entry in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is a space after the comma in your original string, then explode() will return something like ["SDGCC", " ARISE", " SDGFS"].

This will cause your LIKE clause to only match the first word. Try using trim():

```
$word=trim($key);
$safe=mysql_real_escape_string( $word );
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dept_logintags WHERE tag LIKE '%".$safe."%'");
```

EDIT: As Artelius mentioned, always escape user-submitted data to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 34):

Try

```
$tags = explode(',',$string);

foreach($tags as $key) {    
    echo '"'.$key.'"<br/>';    
}
```

My guess is that you are getting a space before ARISE and SDGFS.

Also, make sure you always [escape strings](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) properly before putting them into MySQL queries!! Otherwise someone can send tainted input to your server and wreak havoc on your database. (This is called a [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).)